# Why is DNS lookup slow to specific domains only?

Tags: domain-name-system, cache, nslookup, dig

We're running Windows DNS servers, but they are not authoritative. So we point to caching servers as forwarders.

That said, for the following two domains we get a rather long delay in DNS lookup ***IF*** the domain hasn't already been cached to our internal DNS.

- internet2.edu
- postgresql.org

So far, we haven't identified any other domains that show such symptom.

I've done a packet capture on port 53 and tested `dig` with and without the `+trace` option.

Once it's cached on our DNS server, the subsequent queries come back very quickly using `dig` with `+trace`. Without `+trace` option it caches the `NS` information and some `A` records (dns, dns2, dns3) rather quickly. It continues to return `status: SERVFAIL` until it finally caches the `A` record for `internet.edu`. Once cached, the lookup is super fast as expected. If the `A` record is deleted from cache and the long delay occurs once again.

Any ideas as to why this might be occurring?

```
$ time dig internet2.edu @dc01

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6 <<>> +time=300 internet2.edu @dc01
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 33488
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;internet2.edu.                 IN      A

;; Query time: 10401 msec
;; SERVER: x.x.x.x#53(x.x.x.x)
;; WHEN: Thu Sep  8 13:37:55 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 31


real    0m15.411s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.004s



$ time dig internet2.edu @dc01

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6 <<>> internet2.edu @dc01
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 65026
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;internet2.edu.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
internet2.edu.          56      IN      A       207.75.164.248

;; Query time: 2335 msec
;; SERVER: x.x.x.x#53(x.x.x.x)
;; WHEN: Thu Sep  8 13:39:09 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47


real    0m2.340s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the actual output of your `dig +trace` that reported servfail.

Comment: It would be helpful if your post wasn't formatted worse than a bathroom stall solicitation ad. (EDIT: There, I fixed it. You're welcome, and upvoted.)